# Firebase list order by

Tags: typescript, firebase, ionic-framework

I have a firebase list and Im trying to order it by "time" node. How can I do that in typescript? Thanks!

page.ts:

```
// Get Chat Reference
    chatsProvider.getChatRef(this.company, this.uid, this.interlocutor)
    .then((chatRef:any) => {  
        this.chats = this.db.list(chatRef);
    });

ChatProvider.ts

// get list of Chats of a Logged In User
  getChats() {
    return this.up.getCompany().then(company => {
        return this.up.getUid().then(uid => {
            let chats = this.db.list(`/companies/${company}/users/${uid}/chats`);
            return chats;
        });
     });
  }
```

Comment: which of the codes do you want to order the // Get Chat Reference or // get list of Chats of a Logged In User

Comment: seems like you are using angularfire2

Answer (score 2):

Considering that you are using Angularfire2 , all you have to do is this.

```
this.chats = this.db.list(chatRef, {
  query: {
    orderByChild: "time"
  });
```

> If you want to get the list in descending order, I would advise that you store your time as negative timestamp